# How can I replace text, such as quotes or tags, in pairs?

Tags: tags, quotes

I would like to convert the text `<b>^FTest</b>` to `<div class="import">FTest</div>`, such that the end tag will only be matched and replaced if the start tag was also matched and replaced.

For a simpler analogy: how can I easily switch between the following:

```
This is a "simple" test, yes, a "simple" test, that's right a "simple" test.
This is a [simple] test, yes, a [simple] test, that's right a [simple] test.
This is a **simple** test, yes, a **simple** test, that's right a **simple** test.
This is a <b>simple</b> test, yes a <b>simple</b> test, that's right a <b>simple</b> test.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP function should suffice:

```
function replacepairs($start, $end, $newstart, $newend, $string) {
  $changed = 1;
  while ($changed == 1) {
    $changed = 0;
    $startpos = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($startpos !== FALSE) {
      $endpos = strpos($string, $end, $startpos + strlen($start));
      if ($endpos !== FALSE) {
        $stringltstart = 0;
        $stringltlength = $startpos - $stringltstart;
        $stringlt = substr($string, $stringltstart, $stringltlength);
        $stringeqstart = $startpos + strlen($start);
        $stringeqlength = $endpos - $stringeqstart;
        $stringeq = substr($string, $stringeqstart, $stringeqlength);
        $stringgtstart = $endpos + strlen($end);
        $stringgtlength = strlen($string) - $stringgtstart;
        $stringgt = substr($string, $stringgtstart, $stringgtlength);
        $string = $stringlt.$newstart.$stringeq.$newend.$stringgt;
        $changed = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return $string;
}

$string = 'This is a "simple" test, yes, a "simple" test, that\'s right a "simple" test.';
echo $string.'<br>'."\n";
$string = replacepairs('"', '"', '[', ']', $string);
echo $string.'<br>'."\n";
$string = replacepairs('[', ']', '**', '**', $string);
echo $string.'<br>'."\n";
$string = replacepairs('**', '**', '<b>', '</b>', $string);
echo $string.'<br>'."\n";
```